# Android - Sliding button (arrow)

Tags: android

I have an "arrow" image on the right edge of the screen, pointing right.
It is a part of a bigger image hidden right, out of the screen.
By cliking on this arrow, i'd like it to point and slide to the left dragging within the screen the rest of the image that was hidden.
If I can, I'd also like to set the sliding speed of the sliding image.
Something like this:
[image: What I'd like to obtain]
Is it possible?

Comment: Can you include  some screenshots?

Comment: perform animation on button click.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, **Yes**, it is possible.

Hopefully you are using a fixed width for your item in which case you can just get it in `onCreate()` and initiate your `ValueAnimator`. If not you will need to wait for the layout to be drawn and get your width `onGlobalLayout` callback.

```
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate(..)
    ...
    init();
    ...
}
```

like so:

```
private void init(){
    mButtonView = findViewById(R.id.button_view);
    ImageView arrowButton = mButtonView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_image_container);
    arrowButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    int visibleLength = arrowButton.getWidth();
    int totalLength = mButtonView.getWidth();
    int translationDistance = totalLength - visibleLength;
    mButtonTranslator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,translationDistance);
    mButtonTranslator.addUpdateListener((animatedValue)->{
        float distanceTraveled = (float)animatedValue.getAnimatedValue();
        mButtonView.setTranslationX(distanceTraveled);
    });
}
```

Implement `View.OnClickListener` and add a toggle method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.R.id.arrow_image_container:
            toggleButton();
            break;
    }
}
```

Have a boolean member (mIsButtonVisible) to hold visibility state:

```
private void toggleButton(){
    if (mIsButtonVisible){
        hideButton(true);
    } else {
        showButton(true);
    }
}
```

show:

```
private void showButton(boolean animate){
    if (!mIsButtonVisible){
        mButtonTranslator.setDuration(animate ? ANIMATION_DURATION_IN_MILLIS : 0);
        mButtonTranslator.start();
        mIsButtonVisible = true; 
    }
}
```

and hide:

```
private void hideButton(boolean animate){
    if (mIsButtonVisible){
        mButtonTranslator.setDuration(animate ? ANIMATION_DURATION_IN_MILLIS : 0);
        mButtonTranslator.reverse();
        mIsButtonVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Once initialisation is done and you have your animator initialised you can hide the button off the screen in `onViewCreated()`:

```
hideButton(false);
```

Comment: hi bko, but on mButtonView, AndroidStudio shows me the message: "Required: android.widget.ImageView, Found: android.view.View"